# Edmonds maximum matching algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, graph, matching

I have searched all over the internet trying to find example code in PHP but I am unable to do so. What I am trying to do is match courses to rooms where courses have a set of rooms that they are compatible with.

example: course A can be taught in rooms X, Y and Z, Course B rooms P and Q ect.

Each course can be matched to exactly one room in a given timeslot. I have to create a function that will accept these two sets of rooms and courses and output a maximum matching. Can anyone provide source code in PHP that could get me started? I've never built an algorithm for matching before and don't really know where to begin.

Comment: How are you storing/retrieving your data(courses, rooms)? Or have you gotten to that point yet?

Comment: Pseudo code is in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds's_matching_algorithm, you can probably start from there?

Comment: The setup you're describing is a **bipartite graph**, and there are algorithms for finding maximum matchings in bipartite graphs that are *much* faster than Edmonds' algorithm.  You will almost certainly have better luck finding and implementing one of these algorithms.

Comment: The data is stored in and retrieved from a mysql database. @templatetypedef I agree there are much faster algorithms. I believe the Hopcroft-Karp bipartite matching algorithm is faster such as [this one](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/123641-hopcroft-karp-bipartite-matching/). But I dont know how to go about writing the actual code to accept as input an associative array of course name and room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Igor Naverniouk's [library](http://shygypsy.com/tools/) code for [Bipartite Matching](http://shygypsy.com/tools/bpm.cpp). It's written in C++, but you can easily convert it to PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much this is definitely a start in the right direction for me. However I am still not sure about the format of the input matrix. Upon further reading I found out that PHP uses matrices as 2D arrays. For this code to work the input must be an m x n matrix which will have a value 1 if there is a matching and 0 for no matching. Should I have a matrix such that $matrix['course_name']['room_name'] = 1 for match and 0 for no match or is it that I have to assign a unique number for each course name and room name and use these as the indexes of the array?

Comment: I think you should assign unique number (incremental, from 1 to m) for each course and room (from 1 to n). Of course, it is possible to modify the code to use names as indices, but I think this would be a bit slow.